# Unity - Animator Controller - Store previous state

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I have a locker with 4 drawers. Every drawer is an individual object. Every drawer has its own animation for opening it. I have a problem with transition. If I open the first drawer and then open the second (or third), the first drawer will automatically close.

The next picture shows the object after the first animation (ThirdDrawer_Open)

[image]

The next picture shows the object after the second animation (SecondDrawer_Open)

[image]

I want to store the previous state of animation so when I open the second drawer, the previous one doesn't close/end.

Comment: Most likely a [`Write defaults issues`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-mecanim-setting-write-defaults.278401/).

Comment: @TEEBQNE you are a life saver. How can I mark this comment as an answer?

Comment: I can write up an answer and you can accept that. I'll be a bit more clear with the answer than a comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Animation States`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html) docs, there are various exposed properties on states that you can edit. One property is called `Write Defaults`. From the docs, it is described as

> Whether or not the AnimatorStates writes back the default values for
> properties that are not animated by its Motion.

In your case, if this is enabled whenever you change your states for drawers, it will write the defaults back to the other drawers causing them to close. A solution would be to un-toggle this property so defaults are not written, or you can forcibly overwrite these values at runtime using [`WriteDefaultValues`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.WriteDefaultValues.html). I generally prefer the prior solution as `WriteDefaults` can be a headache to figure out and work with at times.